# Hash::make not working route.php file

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having auth problems in my new laravel 4 app.
The one odd thing I have noticed and this might be why is that when I do:

```
var_dump(Hash::check('secret', Hash::make('secret')));
```

in the DB seeder (where I create my hashed passwords) I get true.

When I run that same command directly in a route, I get false.

Also, when I do a simple:

```
var_dump(Hash::make('secret'));
```

directly in the route it is still false.

Is this broken or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with your install. This is what I get:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    var_dump(Hash::make('secret'));  // Gives a bcrypt string output
    var_dump(Hash::check('secret', Hash::make('secret'))); // Output true
}
```

Did you do a composer update, and forget to update the app itself? That is the most common cause of Laravel 4 issues at the moment.

[This forum pos](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=5367)t gives a detailed answer on how to update the main L4 app after a composer update.

Edit: I will post the forum stuff here - because you need to be logged in to Laravel forums to see beta section:

> If you run composer update and experience problems after doing so, you most
>   likely need to merge in changes from the application skeleton, which
>   is the develop branch of laravel/laravel.
>
> If you originally cloned this repository and still share a git history
>   with it, you can usually merge in changes easily. Assuming your remote
>   is 'upstream' pointed at this repository, you can do the following:

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/develop
```

> Alternatively you could cherry pick in individual commits from the develop branch, but I won't cover that here.
>
> If you downloaded the zip distribution originally or removed the
>   upstream history, you can still resolve your problem manually. Look at
>   the commits on this branch and make any changes not present in your
>   application. Usually the breaking changes are simple configuration
>   changes.
>
> Once Laravel 4 stable has been released the need to do this will be
>   much less frequent, but these changes can still occur. Keep in mind
>   that during this beta application breaking changes are very likely to
>   happen.

*Thanks to Kindari for the forum post.*

Comment: I've updated with the zip from github(https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/develop.zip) and re-setup my config. Composer is also up to date. Still getting bool(false) on those in my route. I agree something must be broken though - an older install on another app works with latest composer update.

Comment: FYI - I just downloaded the latest laravel app, and installed the latest composer - works for me... Did you override any classes or something? Did you try with a blank clean install, or in your app?

Comment: I am still getting boolean false for both conditions on a new fresh install from latest development branch. All I did was a composer update and added the Hash statements into the '/' route. I can also not Hash from a controller - it only works in the db seeder. Was starting to think it might be my PHP install but Hash still works on an older laravel app with latest composer update.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Do you have PHP errors turned on? Hash() requires Crypt - perhaps that is your issue?

Comment: Yep, errors are on and I'm not getting anything in any log files. Crypt is working - my db seeder crypts fine. My older app runs under the same xampp install. I'll try on some different machines tomorrow. Will keep this updated.

Comment: The composer update used a new package by ircmaxell to do hashing. This is where my problem came in as bcrypt with blowfish was broken on my system. My PHP cli was fine but not my cgi one. After upgrading (actually moving over to a nginx setup) all was working fine again.