# Laravel, how to get the environment value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I know that I can access the environment value using the global `$env` variable, but is there *the right way* to get this value?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You're in luck - [this was just added in Beta 4 - see here for details](https://github.com/laravel/framework#beta-4)

> Added App::environment method.

**Edit:** these are now a number of various ways to get the environment variable as of Laravel 4.1

```
App::environment()
app()->environment()
app()->env
$GLOBALS['env'] // not recommended - but it is possible
```

You can also specifically check for if the current environment is set to 'local'

```
App::isLocal()
app()->isLocal()
```

...or 'production'

```
App::isProduction()
app()->isProduction()
```

You can also specifically check for if the current environment is set to 'testing'

```
App::runningUnitTests()
app()->runningUnitTests()
```

Comment: Hmmm, don't have the Beta 4 yet, do you know how I can upgrade?

Comment: simple - run "composer update". Then read the 2nd half of this answer - which talks about how to update your app install aswell: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14909192/1317935

Answer (score 27):

You can also use `app()->env`.

Answer (score 26):

In Laravel 4 and 5, the [Laravel official docs](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration) suggest using:

```
$environment = App::environment();
```

> You may also pass arguments to the environment method to check if the
>   environment matches a given value:

```
if (App::environment('local'))
{
    // The environment is local
}

if (App::environment('local', 'staging'))
{
    // The environment is either local OR staging...
}
```

Comment: Still the current advice for Laravel 8 in 2021.