# Get environment value in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, config

In my .env file I have the following:

```
IMAP_HOSTNAME_TEST=imap.gmail.com
IMAP_USERNAME_TEST=myemail@gmail.com
IMAP_PASSWORD_TEST=mypw
```

Now I would like to use them in my controller. I've tried this, but without any result:

```
$hostname = config('IMAP_HOSTNAME_TEST');
```

The $hostname variable is equal to null. How can I use these configuration variables in my controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4: how can I get the environment value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935846/laravel-4-how-can-i-get-the-environment-value)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Try it with:

```
<?php $hostname = env("IMAP_HOSTNAME_TEST", "somedefaultvalue"); ?>
```

Comment: `somedefaultvalue` can be any default value in case `env` does not exists.

Comment: Using `env()` can lead to unexpected issues, see Grant's answer on this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263107/get-environment-value-in-controller/54286878#54286878.

Comment: Doesn't work for Laravel 5.5. Please go down to find an answer by Masum Ahmed Sarkar

Comment: Add a reducted form of this in the config/app.php file in Laravel 8^ and it will work.
```'hostname' = env('IMAP_HOSTNAME_TEST');```

Answer (score 96):

***It Doesn't work in Laravel 5.3+ if you want to try to access the value from the controller like below. It always returns null***

```
<?php

    $value = env('MY_VALUE', 'default_value');
```

***SOLUTION: Rather, you need to create a file in the configuration folder, say values.php and then
write the code like below***

#### File *values.php*

```
<?php

    return [

        'myvalue' => env('MY_VALUE',null),

        // Add other values as you wish
```

***Then access the value in your controller with the following code***

```
<?php

    $value = \Config::get('values.myvalue')
```

***Where "values" is the filename followed by the key "myvalue".***

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted... It's the correct answer (mostly) for L5.3+. But using your example filename of `values.php`, you'd actually reference it in the controller as `$value = config('values.myvalue');`

Comment: Don't forget to `php artisan config:cache` to commit config changes.

Answer (score 93):

To simplify: Only configuration files can access [environment variables](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/environment_variable) - and then pass them on.

**Step 1.)** Add your variable to your `.env` file, for example,

```
EXAMPLE_URL="http://google.com"
```

**Step 2.)** Create a new file inside of the `config` folder, with any name, for example,

```
config/example.php
```

**Step 3.)** Inside of this new file, I add an array being returned, containing that environment variable.

```
<?php
return [
  'url' => env('EXAMPLE_URL')
];
```

**Step 4.)** Because I named it "example", my configuration 'namespace' is now example. So now, in my controller I can access this variable with:

```
$url = \config('example.url');
```

**Tip** - if you add `use Config;` at the top of your controller, you don't need the backslash (which designates the root namespace). For example,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Config; // Added this line

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function url() {
        return config('example.url');
    }
}
```

Finally, commit the changes:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

***--- IMPORTANT ---*** Remember to enter `php artisan optimize:clear` into the console once you have created your example.php file. Configuration files and variables are cached, so if you make changes you need to flush that cache - the same applies to the `.env` file being changed / added to.

Comment: php artisan config:cache crash my aplication

Comment: @FelipeCastillo means your application has an issue in its configuration - because that command only flushes the cache

Comment: config() is the helper function and does NOT need the `use Config;`. With the use statement you can use the alias `Config` for `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class` like for example: `Config::get('example.url')`

Comment: @petermortensen @Grant, this is a great answer. My question is why does this work as opposed to just using laravels ```env()``` helper method?

Comment: @PA-GW The env() helper accesses only the (often security sensitive) environment variables stored in the .env file. You'll notice in my opening line, I mentioned that it appears that (at least as of the date answering this question) configuration files are the only files that are able to access those sensitive super globals.

Comment: @CodeConnoisseur 4 years late, but an answer none-the-less: avoids issues related to runtime changes in environment variables and simplifies deployment across different environments

Answer (score 32):

All of the variables listed in  `.env` file will be loaded into the `$_ENV` PHP super-global when your application receives a request. [Check out the Laravel configuration page](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration).

```
$_ENV['yourkeyhere'];
```

Comment: This is the correct and the best answer on how to get values from `.env` file.

Comment: Not working for me in `laravel 9` controller

Answer (score 6):

You can use with this format (tested on Laravel 5.5). In my case I used it for gettting the data of database connections and use on Controller:

```
$User = env('DB_USERNAMEchild','');
$Pass = env('DB_PASSWORDchild','');
```

The second parameter can be null, or set any default in case of DB_USERNAMEchild is null.

Your .env file can be the same:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=FATHERBD
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password

DB_DATABASEchild=ZTEST
DB_USERNAMEchild=root
DB_PASSWORDchild=passwordofchild
```

Comment: Where did you place this code, `config/app.php` or the controller/view? This worked for me on `Laravel 5.2` but doesn't seem to on `Laravel 5.3+`. Since you're specifying `Laravel 5.5`, I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: i have placed this code on app/Http/ExampleController.php

Answer (score 5):

It's a better idea to put your configuration variables in a configuration  file.

In your case, I would suggest putting your variables in **config/mail.php** like:

```
'imap_hostname' => env('IMAP_HOSTNAME_TEST', 'imap.gmail.com')
```

And refer to them by

```
config('mail.imap_hostname')
```

It first tries to get the configuration variable value in the **.env** file and if it couldn't find the variable value in the **.env** file, it will get the variable value from file **config/mail.php**.

Answer (score 3):

As @Rajib pointed out, You can't access your env variables using `config('myVariable')`

1. You have to add the variable to .env file first.
2. Add the variable to some config file in `config` directory. I usually add to `config/app.php`
3. Once done, will access them like `Config::get('fileWhichContainsVariable.Variable');` using the `Config` Facade

Probably You will have to clear config cache using `php artisan config:clear`
AND
you will also have to restart server.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the value into your `.env` file

```
 VALUE=somevalue
on the controller 
$_ENV['VALUE']
or
env('VALUE')
```

if it doesn't work, run this command

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer not effective anymore after `Laravel 5.2` version:

To get environment values in controllers or (any php file in laravel project) you have tow cases:

**Case 1 (Predefined keys)**: If you need to get value from `.env` file which created by Laravel project as (default .env file), or by third party plugin you already installed it and follow the correct installation procedure of installation, See this answer for explain: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69707775/2877427

**Case 2 (**Not predefined** keys - if you need generate new custom environment key)**: to do that follow these instructions:

1 -Add your custom key in `.env` file, for example i will add this key:

```
UNIFONIC_APP_ID=xx2Erdasd7Ik7XfdesfaV9HX47
```

2- Add new php file in `laravel_root/config` folder, for example i will add this file `config/custom.php` and its contents like this:

```
return [

    'unifonic_id' => env('UNIFONIC_APP_ID' , 'Here Default value will used of UNIFONIC_APP_ID not defined in .env file'),

];
```

3- Run these tow commands in terminal:

> ```
> php artisan config:clear
> php artisan config:cache
> ```

4 - Now in any php file (Controllers, Models, Views, ... etc) you can call this function:

> config('custom.unifonic_id');

Where `custom` is the name of php file which generated in `step 2`, and `unifonic_id` is the key of array which defined in `step 2`

This will return value if `UNIFONIC_APP_ID` which defined in `.env`, if not exists will return default value which defined in config file `in step 2`

> Note 1: config file can return multi dimensions array, take look for
> structers of config files which located in `laravel_root/config`
> folder.

> Note 2: you can modify file `laravel_root/config/services.php` insted
> of create new config file...

Answer (score 2):

**In Controller**

```
$hostname = $_ENV['IMAP_HOSTNAME_TEST']; (or) $hostname = env('IMAP_HOSTNAME_TEST');
```

**In blade.view**

```
{{$_ENV['IMAP_HOSTNAME_TEST']}}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Laravel 7` I access `.env` variables like this.

You already have a file called `services.php` inside config folder.

define a new array like below

```
    'env_var'=>[
        'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
    ]
```

now run `php artisan config:cache`

inside your controller import `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;`

Now you can access like these

```
        $server = Config::get('services.env_var.host');
        $username = Config::get('services.env_var.username');
        $password = Config::get('services.env_var.password');
        $database = Config::get('services.env_var.database');
```

I hope it help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the environment variable like this.

Inside the `.env` file you write

```
IMAP_HOSTNAME_TEST=imap.gmail.com  // I am okay with this
```

Next, inside the `config` folder there is a file, mail.php. You may use this file to code. As you are working with mail functionality. You might use another file as well.

```
return [

//..... other declarations
'imap_hostname_test' => env('IMAP_HOSTNAME_TEST'),
// You are hiding the value inside the configuration as well

];
```

You can call the variable from a controller using `'config(`.
Whatever file you are using inside config folder. You need to use that `file name (without extension) + '.' + 'variable name' + ')'`. In the current case you can call the variable as follows.

```
$hostname = config('mail.imap_hostname_test');
```

Since you declare the variable inside mail.php and the variable name is `imap_hostname_test`, you need to call it like this. If you declare this variable inside `app.php` then you should call

```
$hostname = config('app.imap_hostname_test');
```

Answer (score 0):

In config/app.php file make a instance of env variable like `'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel')`
& In your controller call it like `config('app.name')`

Run following commands `php artisan config:cache` `php artisan cache:clear` if it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In the book of Matt Stauffer he suggest to create an array in your `config/app.php` to add the variable and then anywhere you reference to it with:

```
$myvariable = new Namearray(config('fileWhichContainsVariable.array.ConfigKeyVariable'))
```

Have try this solution? is good ?

Answer (score 0):

env('MAIL_USERNAME', '');

if not working hit command: php artisan config:clear