# How do I use values from .env in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi ?I am just learning to use Laravel framework and having trouble understanding how to use the values stored in the `.env` file. I have created a template application using `artisan` and it works. 
In the default welcome blade is the code

```
<div class="title m-b-md">
     Laravel <--/*this text needs to change */
</div>
```

In the file `.env` is the lines:

```
APP_NAME=SomeAppName
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:zUm/qFNKTV4gRw6bFcIdOfm5rTzrS8JP1bj2KIz8Rl4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

How do i reference the `.env` file so that the welcome page shows the value of `APP_NAME` ("SomeAppName") instead of "Laravel"?

p.s have tried `{{ getenv('APP_NAME') }}` and `{{ config('app.name', 'SomeAppName') }}` but former gives blank and latter still prints out "Laravel"

Comment: Take a look at some of the files in the `config` folder. Also, you might need to `php artisan config:clear` for new settings to take effect

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263107/get-environment-value-in-controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Laravel .env variables in blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040967/accessing-laravel-env-variables-in-blade)

Answer (score 10):

It seems both of @stan & @yash above answers are partially correct.

Please Follow below links:

1. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/printing-env-variables-in-view
2. [Accessing Laravel .env variables in blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040967/accessing-laravel-env-variables-in-blade)

According to above what you need to do is as below

```
<div class="title m-b-md">
      {{ env('APP_NAME') }}
</div>
```

Then from console you need to clear cache.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 8):

```
<div class="title m-b-md">
     {{ env('APP_NAME') }}
</div>
```

If your running local environment server. Firstly you restart your local environment server and try this.

And if you enabled config cache than run the commands below

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Thanks all for amazingly fast response that even worked.

Comment: One small question, is that supposed to be `clear:config` or `config:clear`? etc.

Comment: @Mikedavison it shoule be `php artisan config:clear and cache:clear` since the above command will give this error **There are no commands defined in the "clear" namespace.**

Answer (score 3):

In Blade you could do something like:

```
{{ env('APP_URL')
```

In a controller or PHP Class:

```
env('APP_URL')
```