# Move a line from controller to new file and call it in laravel

Tags: laravel, gitignore

ThisController in my local PC's Laravel, there is a line like this.

```
$result = shell_exec('C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe test.py '. $text);
```

but, this is local PC path. so if I push to web server, I need to change to

```
$result = shell_exec('usr\bin\Python test.py '. $text);
```

So, I want to cut this line and paste into a new file, and I want to call this line from the new file via ThisContoroller. So, I can make the file to gitignore and I don't get conflict.

But I don't know how to do it. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like something to put in your `.env` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to ceejayoz's comment, yes, I could do with .env file.
With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263107/get-environment-value-in-controller) thread's answer.