# How to access the laravel .env variables inside itself

Tags: php, laravel

I need to ask stupid question but my question to access .env variable inside it self not from php  :

If i have `.env` file for larvel5.4 and i have `APP_URL` Like this :

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:7qLJMqTxrAPk+tLJscVlmrzf2H16tAfbSoCZuleCkxQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

and i have multi config variable use the domain link like this :

```
#Facebook

FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL=http://localhost:8000/en/portal/facebook_login
FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:8000/en/portal/facebook_callback

#Twitter

TWITTER_LOGIN_URL=http://localhost:8000/en/portal/twitter_login
TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:8000/en/portal/twitter_callback

#Google

GOOGLE_LOGIN_URL=http://localhost:8000/en/portal/google_login
GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL=http://localhost:8000/en/portal/google_callback
```

is there way to access the APP_URL in the same file like this :

```
FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL= APP_URL /en/portal/facebook_login
```

Please i am new member don't give me minus for this question.

Thank you all

Comment: I think its same like txt file, so there is nothing dynamic, whatever you specify will be static.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4: how can I get the environment value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935846/laravel-4-how-can-i-get-the-environment-value)

Comment: i think that too but when you create composer the composer read it as a code file like no space or missing variable .. because that i am wondering if there way to deal with this file .. thank you for your answer

Comment: This question is creating a lot bad practices...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep things simple, while accessing ENV variables you can easily do the following:

Env file:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL=/en/portal/facebook_login
FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL=/en/portal/facebook_callback
```

in Laravel:

```
env('APP_URL') . env('FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL');
```

And Yes we can do that if needed use following syntax:

.env file:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL=${APP_URL}/en/portal/facebook_login
FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL=${APP_URL}/en/portal/facebook_callback
```

Comment: You can use environment variables inside .env files by using the ${ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE} syntax. OP saying 'There is no way' is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

While other answers are correct about using variables stored in `.env`. I think it's going to be neater, if you do the following:

```
url(env('FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL'))
```

or:

```
url(env('FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL'))
```

`url()` uses `APP_URL` so you don't need to concatenate your `.env` variables.

Answer (score 1):

In **.env** file:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL="${APP_URL}/en/portal/facebook_login"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define constant in app/config/constant.php

```
define('FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL','http://localhost:8000/en/portal/facebook_login');
define('FACEBOOK_CALLBACK_URL','http://localhost:8000/en/portal/facebook_callback');

echo FACEBOOK_LOGIN_URL;
```

And so on for other url's , I hope it will solve your problem !

Comment: thank you for your answer it's right outsude the .env file but i need it inside the .env file