# How do I update the /app folder when Laravel is updated?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Sometimes I have problems with my Laravel project after running `composer update`.  I believe this is caused by changes in the Laravel application skeleton (https://github.com/laravel/laravel).  How do I update my local project to reflect those changes?

Comment: This question is answered (but not asked) on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909192/hashmake-not-working-route-php-file -- I figured it would be easier to find if it were asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

From the awesome forum post on the Laravel forums by Kindari (http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=5367):

> If you originally cloned this repository and still share a git history
>   with it, you can usually merge in changes easily. Assuming your remote
>   is 'upstream' pointed at this repository, you can do the following:

```
 git fetch upstream 
 git merge upstream/develop
```

> Alternatively you could cherry pick in individual commits 
>   from the develop branch, but I won't cover that here.
>
> If you downloaded the zip distribution originally or
>   removed the upstream history, you can still resolve your problem
>   manually. Look at the commits on this branch and make any changes not
>   present in your application. Usually the breaking changes are simple
>   configuration changes.

Since *most* of the changes are likely to be simple configuration changes,
another option is to do a diff on the root folder and the /app folder.  You'll mostly see your own configuration, but you'll also see any new configuration items that you should add.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use git pull request. A git pull request does a git fetch followed by a git merge. It works for me nicely. In other words, A git pull is what you would do to bring your repository up to date with a remote repository.