# Laravel 4: Hash::make not returning a proper value

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use `Hash::make()` in my application and I'm having trouble getting it to work.  I've been trying to use the documentation on the Laravel 3 site, since I can't find anything on the Laravel 4 documentation on it.

When I try to insert `Hash::make($password)` into my database, it saves the value as 0.  My field is `varchar` and it has a length of 100, which should be long enough.  I've tried inserting into different fields in my database, and it always saves as 0.  I tried setting `$password` to a test string, rather than what's coming from the form and it still saves as 0.  If I insert `$password` without the `Hash::make()` it stores my password.

I tried echoing `Hash::make('test`) on my page and I got nothing echoed back.  No output at all.  I guess that's why I'm inserting 0 into the database when I try to store the value.

Could this be related to the application key that you set with `key:generate` through Artisan?  I discovered I hadn't set that and when I tried to set it, it tells me it is already set?  How do I reset the key?

Comment: the app key created by artisan is used for session cookies but doesn't keep Hash::make() from working. However for help getting the key set, I noticed if it doesn't contain the original text 'key' => 'YourSecretKey!!!', the key:generate command thinks the key is already set(even if it is an empty string). I'm testing on a fully updated L4 and Hash::make('hello') returns a 64 character hashed string as it should. Not sure but I think it will always be 64 char so your 100 char field should be fine.

Comment: I tested what you said about the key and you are correct.  What could be causing issue with `Hash::make()`?

Comment: Is `echo Hash::make('hello')` valid PHP that will return the hash?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe a full app update. Similar or maybe same issue here has a link to instructions for updating the app folder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909192/hashmake-not-working-route-php-file

Comment: Yep, in most cases you want to use return but echo Hash::make('hello') works as well as return or var_dump() for testing if it's working.

Comment: `var_dump` returns a boolean, false.  What's up with that?

Comment: Ran `composer update` and I'm still having the problem.

Comment: It's our turnkey server.  Something is misconfigured there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Requirements of Laravel 4](http://four.laravel.com/docs/installation)

- PHP >= 5.3.7
- MCrypt PHP Extension

I suspect you do not have the MCrypt PHP extension enabled. You can run `phpinfo()` to confirm.

Comment: The problem actually turned out to to be the reverse.  I had PHP 5.3.3.  Upgrading solved the problem.